# Can Microsoft.HPC.SDK be used in a blazor server app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, hpc

I am trying to piece together a piece of code from a web app project into my blazor server application and am having issues when it comes to using Microsoft.HPC. Specifically, I am getting an error when I use SessionStartInfo. Here is the following code

```
SessionStartInfo info = null;
        
info = new SessionStartInfo("example", "example");
```

When I run this, the second line gives me the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.String System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()'.'

I am wondering if it is even possible to use Microsoft.HPC.SDK package in a blazor app, but if not, what would be the alternative?

Comment: You can [see for yourself](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.HPC.SDK/), it only support .NET 4.x. So: No, not for Blazor.

Comment: Any alternative suggestions?